# Set llvm fastmath flags from OCaml

Tags: optimization, ocaml, llvm

I am developing a small special-purpose compiler using OCaml/llvm. So far everything works out fine, but I am stuck at the disposal of IEE-754 semantics for my floating point operations.

There is a way to specify fast math flags for every floating point instruction according to the llvm documnentation:

http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#fastmath

Unfortunately, I could not figure out, how to set these flags using OCaml. All I can use is:

```
val build_fadd : llvalue -> llvalue -> string -> llbuilder -> llvalue
```

So is flagging an instruction not implemented in the OCaml bindings? If it isn't, how would I change a flag using an external C-function for an existing instruction?